# Dynatrace login failure after password change

Tags: windows, ldap, dynatrace

I have installed the Dynatrace client and I've been using if for months. After a Windows password reset I am getting this error. I have tried entering the new and old password.

```
Error on Login - The login failed because either the specified user name or password is incorrect, or you are not allowed to access this Dynatrace Server.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This could be cache issues or something at the AppMon server:

> If the LDAP server is down completely, LDAP users cannot log in.
>   However, successful user authentications are cached on the AppMon
>   Server for 10 minutes by default. If the same user logs in within this
>   time frame, no LDAP request is sent again and the user's
>   authentication timeout is prolonged. The user's group membership is
>   not verified or updated within this time frame.

You can configure the authentication timeout by changing the value of the following system property in the `dtserver.ini` file:

```
-Dcom.dynatrace.diagnostics.ldapAuthenticationTimeout=600
```

Reference: [Dynatrace AppMon Documentation](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/doc/appmon/administration/user-permissions-and-authentication/users-ldap/#ldap-performance)